# why is async_read_until() NOT wating?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-serialization

When i use boost::async_read_until() with archives it does not wait as it is supposed. As my client and server are a bit long to show, i am going to show the methods where the problem comes in. Please help me dealing with them

```
//client
void doChat()
    {
        cout << "Enter message: ";
        std::getline(cin, m_info.m_message);
        m_info.m_id = 7;

        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive out(ss);

            out & m_info;

            m_string_stream = ss.str();
            m_string_stream += '\n';
        }

        m_sock.async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_string_stream), 
            [this](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes) 
        {
            if (ec == 0){
                doChat();
            } 
        });
```

since i didn`t know how to send the archive object directly, i used string adding '\n' supposing the server will read till '\n'

```
//server
void doChatserver(std::shared_ptr<client> connection)
    {
        boost::asio::async_read_until(connection->m_sock, connection->m_stream_buffer, '\n', 
            [this, connection](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes)
        {
            if (ec == 0)
            {
                {
                    boost::archive::binary_iarchive in_archive(connection->m_stream_buffer);

                    in_archive & connection->m_info;
                }
                doChatserver(connection); //--> problem when calling secondly
            }
        });
    }
```

after the server reads from client, as a callback it calls doChatserver() again but this time it does NOT wait the client`s data to come, and it just crashes!!!
So What is the problem do you think?

Comment: if you have some other idea how to send archive type in boost::asio PLEASE welcome

Comment: the problem why this is (server) crashing is clear, because the doCharserver() does NOT wait when calling a second time as a callback inside itself, the boost::archive::binary_iarchive() object takes a zero parametr and it IS the reason of crashing

Comment: but why the doChatserver() DOES not WAIT the client`s data to come as it DID for the first time but never did for the second time???

Comment: guys sorry i forgot to post the m_info struct

Comment: Actually it is just a simple struct as you may have noticed

Comment: struct blank
{
 int m_id;
 std::string m_message;

 template<typename archive>
 void serialize(archive& ar, const short version)
 {
  ar & m_id;
  ar & m_message;
 }
};

Comment: for both the server and the client

Comment: guys i DO need your help

Comment: @OP please don't be a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, just some pointers..

1) You should call `async_write_some` repeatedly until the buffer is empty.

See remark in [`async_write_some`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_write_some.html) documentation:

> The write operation may not transmit all of the data to the peer. Consider using the `async_write` function if you need to ensure that all data is written before the asynchronous operation completes.

For that reason it is easier to use [`async_write`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) instead which guarantees that all the data in the buffer is sent.

2) You should strip the `\n` from the end of the received data before passing it to `iarchive`, as it doesn't belong to your binary archive.

3) What if your binary stream contains the byte `0A` (`\n`)? read_until will stop prematurely. Consider sending the *length* of the data as integer (e.g. first 4 bytes), followed by the data itself. Don't read until `\n` when dealing with binary data.

Send function:

- calculate binary data size N
- construct a buffer of data size (4 bytes) + data (N bytes)
- send the whole buffer (N + 4 bytes)

Receive function:

- read 4 bytes
- read N data bytes as specified in the previous 4 bytes

  Example:

  `boost::asio::read(socket, streambuf, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(n), ec);`

4) Use a debugger. Break and look what's been read into `connection->m_info`.